# Как лучше обходить массив - через 'forEach' или через 'of'?

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach, операторы

Какой вариант будет лучше, чем и почему?:

```js
function makeSomething_A(params, obj) {
    var ret = [];
    ...
    params.forEach(function(param) {
        var key = param.split('=')[0];
        if (!(key in obj)) {
            ret.push(encodeURI(param));
        }
    });
    ...
    return ret;
};
var myParams = [ ... ];
var myObj = { ... };
...
var A = makeSomething_A(myParams, myObj);
```

```js
function makeSomething_B(params, obj) {
    var ret = [];
    ...
    for (param of params) {
        var key = param.split('=')[0];
        if (!(key in obj)) {
            ret.push(encodeURI(param));
        }
    });
    ...
    return ret;
};
var myParams = [ ... ];
var myObj = { ... };
...
var B = makeSomething_B(myParams, myObj);
```

Лишнее выкинул. Интересуют нюансы/отличия/разница/оптимальность именно между "**forEach**" и "**of**".

Спасибо!

Comment: Без разницы. Впрочем стоит принять во внимание https://twitter.com/leaverou/status/936709376005607424

Comment: Тут - https://habrahabr.ru/post/46787/ - пишут про другое, но выходит что вроде как при идентичной логике разница может быть по нагрузке/скорости. Может и с моими этими есть аналогичные отличия?

Comment: Статья почти 10-летней давности

Comment: Разница по скорости может быть, но если вы эту функцию не выполняете десятки тысяч раз в секунду, то разницу вы не заметите. Поэтому пишите как удобнее и логичнее в вашем конкретном случае